Communicate problem between client and server in Google Spreadsheet, google.script.run. doesn't work
I was trying to implement a dialog in Google Spreadsheet using a container-bounded app script. This is a very simple implement, I just want the user to be able to add a new item by submitting content in the dialog, and search the cell with non-white background color and export them in PDF.
Unluckily, I've met some problem with implementation of adding new Item.
Here is the source code from Code.gs:
function addMenuItem() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('My Functions')
  .addItem('Show Dialog', 'showModal')
  .addToUi();
}

function showModal() {
  const userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('modal').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'My modal');
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var formName = formObject.name;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').appendRow([formName]);
}

And code from modal.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      * {
        font-family: 'Comic Neue', cursive;
      }
      input {
        font-size: 18px;
        outline: none;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      button {
        cursor: select;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 7px 15px;
        background-color: #57ff87;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #5555;
      }
      button:active {
        filter: brightness(1.2);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #5550;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().processForm(formObject);
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, and Welcome!</h1>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <input name="name" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </body>

  
</html>

when I try to call the client side function using google.script.run, nothing happens and there are errors that pops out in the console while opening the dialog:

Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit, Message = The…ansport or processing of this request., undefined', name: 'TransportError', stack: 'TransportError: Error code = 10, Path = /wardenini…1922652-warden_bin_i18n_warden__en_gb.js:215:356)'

And When I click submit in the dialog, a new error pops out saying Uncaught.
I've tried many different ways to solve this problem, but still can't fix it.

I have tried to run your code and it seems that appending the row work and Google Script run does something on my end. Can you try to manually from Apps Script just in case you need some authorization allowed. Also, I can see that you have 2 questions here. Can you provide more clarity which part are you having issues with?

@Babanana Thanks for the tip, I call the method SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').appendRow("test"); directly, and there's an error saying Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.appendRow. The Issuees is I want to pass some content from dialog into the sheet, and then I want to export the content of the sheet as pdf. But the import part (Call server side function from client side using google.app.script.run) doesn't work, That is the problem that keep bothering me

@Yunlong What you say in the first part of the comment doesn't match what was said in the question. You'll need to post a new question for the problem mentioned in the comment. P.D. You should pass an array instead of a string as the parameter value of SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.appendRow

I would suggest this too, what Wicket suggested Yunlong, please clarify the question. Your code works with me. The reason you have this error right now when you manually append row is it is a string. Please use this as a reference. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object). What I suggest in the last comment is to manually running the code without any changes before testing it from the Dialog.

Thanks guys, It is indeed not that clear, I will try to follow your tips, If still run into some problems that I coundn't fix, then I will post a new question about it. I thought the TransportError and Uncaught are the key point why the string didn't passed from client to server, and these error is bacause I somehow made a mistake when calling server-side function.

@Yunlong to avoid the exception you quoted, use .appendRow(["test"]).

Remove .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
The above because, from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode,

The NATIVE and EMULATED modes were deprecated on October 13, 2015 and both are now sunset. Only IFRAME mode is now supported.

Regarding the console error, it's irrelevant. This is thrown even with simple working code. For details, see my answer to There was an error during the transport or processing of this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit

Thanks, I will take a look at the link
